# Explain regular expression - '/_m_/_r_'

Tags: javascript, regex

What is below regular expression matching ? Is '_' a wildcard and '/' an or statement ?

I think its matching any 'm' character or any 'r' character.

```
'/_m_/_r_'
```

Comment: Can you provide more surrounding code?

Comment: That doesn't look like a valid JavaScript regular expression.

Comment: @deceze thats the complete expression.

Comment: Yes, the complete expression... but how is it used? Is that a string that's passed to a `RegExp` constructor...? It's hard to tell.

Comment: @deceze I'm sure if its a valid expression or not. Seems it isn't

Comment: It's a perfectly valid regular expression. It just depends on how it's used exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm just going to assume that's a string literal that's used like this:

```
var r = new RegExp('/_m_/_r_');
```

In that case the expression matches the literal string `/_m_/_r_`. There are no tokens with special meanings in the expression.